# PIG generate data using different load variables

Tags: apache-pig

I have 2 files and i want to generate data using different columns of diff 
files. I want to do something like this:-

Here is my problem with example:-

I have 2 files abc.txt(col1,col2) and xyz.txt(col3,col4) Number of records in both the files differ say abc.txt has 1000 records and xyz.txt has 100 records.
I want to store output in a file such that , i get col1,col2 from abc.txt and col3 from xyz.txt (as we have less records in xyz then abc i want my col3 values to get repeated either randomly  or in same sequence as in input file anything is ok)

```
Input
abc.txt           xyz.txt
col1 col2        col3  col4
 1     A           4      X
 2     B           5      Y
 3     C           6      Z
 4     D
 5     D
 6     F
 7     A

A = LOAD '/user/abc.txt' Using PigStorage('|'); 
B = LOAD '/user/xyz.txt' Using PigStorage('|'); 
C = FOREACH A GENERATE A.$0,A.$1,B.$0;

Output
col1 col2 col3
 1     A    4
 2     B    5
 3     C    6
 4     D    5
 5     D    4
 6     F    4
 7     A    6
```

Is it possible to do this using PIG?

Answer (score 0):

`GENERATE` is not operator in Pig. So you cannot use it to generate data. Pig provides `FOREACH` for iterating over a relation. It works for one relation only. To me it looks like you can generate the data as you have specified in question until you want to perform some sort of `JOIN` on data.

Comment: Somehow i missed FOREACH before GENERATE in my post. My primary question was can i take columns from 2 different files to generate data (like A.$0,B.$0;). To which you said its possible only through join. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Not sure on solution part. Still searching web for same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide sample input and output? If possible I will try.

Comment: Edited my ques with sample input and output.